# Adding desctiptions to Sql Server table and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want add the description of the table  and description to each column in the table so that i can retrieve in future for my reference . Is there any way i can do this in SQL SERVER?
can any sql folk answer me this? many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click design view of table then select the column you want to add description

below the design you can see column properties there is a property named description you can give

description of the column there[image: See this Image]

Comment: what about table description?

Comment: right click the table and select properties window , there you can see extended properties select that then you can add name and value there

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for Extended Properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx